# unpacking of archive failed on file error when installing a rpm pkg

Tags: linux, rpm

I got an error shown below when I'm installing a rpm pkg:
*error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/local/xxxx/help/html/xxx.chm/xxx.html;56498998: cpio: Digest mismatch*

I've tried to find some related topics about this error by google.
Digest mismatch seems to be happened mostly in the %install step when someone building a rpm pkg.

Most of the case about the error: unpacking of archive failed on file was end by cpio:open failed. I think this is different from my error.

So do anyone have some ideas about this error ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it suits better for Unix & Linux SE. Also, the question needs to be improved ,as it seems unclear as of now ,before moving to other SE site.

Answer (score 1):

You can encounter this problem when attempting to install an RPM built for a newer system such as RHEL6 on an older system (RHEL5 or some intermediate version of Fedora).  Here are a few related reports:

- [Re: [opensuse-buildservice] cpio digest mismatch with RHEL6 beta](http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-buildservice/2010-06/msg00055.html)
- [Bug 1156497: cpio digest mismatch when initializing fc19 chroot](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1156497)